# dependence list with two conditions

Tags: php

Hello everyone I need help with my php code

I need to use a dependency list , I have three select fields (filiere,Semestre,module)
the first list is filiere select which takes all the the filieres we have in the data base and we can select one of them
the secend list is semestre which has 6 options (S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6)
the last one is module which depends on the both previous ones (filiere & semestre )

we have in the database this tables

filiere ( Nom_filiere )
module ( Num_module,Nom_module,Nom_filiere,Nom_semestre)

I succeeded to make the last list depends on the first (filiere) but I still have a problem to add a condition on the second one (semestre)

this is my code :

// select.php

```
$query = "SELECT  * FROM filiere";
$result1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);


<script type="text/javascript">
    function getID(val){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "get_module.php",
            data:"get_filiere=" + val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#NOM_MODULE").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<label for="Nom_filiere"  id="Nom_filiere"   >Filieres</label>
<select onChange="getID(this.value);"  id="Nom_filiere"  name="Nom_filiere">

<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>

    <option value="<?php echo $row1[0];?>"><?php echo $row1[0];?></option>

<?php endwhile;?>
</select>

<label for="NOM_semestre">Semestre</label>

<select id="NOM_semestre" name="NOM_semestre" >
    <option value="S1"> S1</option>
    <option value="S1"> S2</option>
    <option value="S1"> S3</option>
    <option value="S1"> S4</option>
    <option value="S1"> S5</option>
    <option value="S1"> S6</option>
</select>


<label for="NOM_MODULE"> Module</label>

    <select class="mdb-select md-form"  id="NOM_MODULE" name="NOM_MODULE[]" multiple>
        <option selected="" disabled="">selest module</option>
    </select>

// get_module.php :

if(isset($_POST['get_filiere'])) { 

    $fid = $_POST['get_filiere'];

    $query2 = "SELECT * from module where NOM_Filiere ='$fid'";

    if($result2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2)) {

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
                echo "<option value=".$row['NUM_Module'].">".$row['Nom_module']."</option>";
            }  
    } else {
        echo "Something went wrong while executing query :: $query";
    }
    exit;
}
```

this code works fine with the first condition I just need to add a condition on Semestre

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two libraries I know that could help you achieve this ...

- Form-Field-Dependency: http://emranahmed.github.io/Form-Field-Dependency/
- DependsOn: https://dstreet.github.io/dependsOn/

They will help you control the dependencies between fields by configuring in a declarative way.